# How to convert time different value of two rows minutes to hour

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time

Here I have dataset with datetime. Here I want to get time different value row by row in my csv file.

So I wrote the code to get the time different value in minutes. Then I want to convert that time different in hour.

That means;

> if time difference value is 30 minutes. in hours 0.5h
>
> if 120 min > 2h

But when I tried to it, it doesn't match with my required format. I just divide that time difference with 60.

my code:

```
df1['time_diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df1["time"])
```

print(df1['time_diff'])

```html
0     2019-08-09 06:15:00
1     2019-08-09 06:45:00
2     2019-08-09 07:45:00
3     2019-08-09 09:00:00
4     2019-08-09 09:25:00
5     2019-08-09 09:30:00
6     2019-08-09 11:00:00
7     2019-08-09 11:30:00
8     2019-08-09 13:30:00
9     2019-08-09 13:50:00
10    2019-08-09 15:00:00
11    2019-08-09 15:25:00
12    2019-08-09 16:25:00
13    2019-08-09 18:00:00
```

```
df1['delta'] = (df1['time_diff']-df1['time_diff'].shift()).fillna(0)
df1['t'] = df1['delta'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(1,'m')).astype('int64')% (24*60)
```

then the result:

[image]

After dividing by 60:

```
df1['t'] = df1['delta'].apply(lambda x: x  / np.timedelta64(1,'m')).astype('int64')% (24*60)/60
```

result:

[image]

comparing each two images you can see in my first picture 30 min is there when I tries to convert into hours it is not showing and it just showing 1 only.

But have to convert 30 min as 0.5 hr.

Expected output:

[![

```html
time_diff in min expected output of time_diff in hour
             0               0
             30             0.5
             60              1
             75           1.25
             25           0.4167
             5            0.083
             90             1.5
             30             0.5
             120             2
             20           0.333
             70           1.33
             25           0.4167
             60              1
             95           1.583
```

Can anyone help me to solve this error?

Comment: Can you add expected output from sample data? also is possible convert pictures to text for possible copy it?

Comment: @jezrael  yes I upload my expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest use [`Series.dt.total_seconds`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.total_seconds.html) with divide by `60` and `3600`:

```
df1['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date']+ ' ' + df1['time'], dayfirst=True)

df1['delta'] = df1['datetimes'].diff().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))

td = df1['delta'].dt.total_seconds()
df1['time_diff in min'] = td.div(60).astype(int)
df1['time_diff in hour'] = td.div(3600)
print (df1)
             datetimes    delta  time_diff in min  time_diff in hour
0  2019-08-09 06:15:00 00:00:00                 0           0.000000
1  2019-08-09 06:45:00 00:30:00                30           0.500000
2  2019-08-09 07:45:00 01:00:00                60           1.000000
3  2019-08-09 09:00:00 01:15:00                75           1.250000
4  2019-08-09 09:25:00 00:25:00                25           0.416667
5  2019-08-09 09:30:00 00:05:00                 5           0.083333
6  2019-08-09 11:00:00 01:30:00                90           1.500000
7  2019-08-09 11:30:00 00:30:00                30           0.500000
8  2019-08-09 13:30:00 02:00:00               120           2.000000
9  2019-08-09 13:50:00 00:20:00                20           0.333333
10 2019-08-09 15:00:00 01:10:00                70           1.166667
11 2019-08-09 15:25:00 00:25:00                25           0.416667
12 2019-08-09 16:25:00 01:00:00                60           1.000000
13 2019-08-09 18:00:00 01:35:00                95           1.583333
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast reply. But still it showing same result as shown as second result.

Comment: @team - A bit simplify solution, for me working nice

Comment: @ jezrael  Okay let me try once again. I tried it again showing the same results

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fpiwFdNqhqKvec8RfqDZWqfm-LKYTRJ3sKzPfKwD0qs/edit#gid=399457400  , here is my csv file link, you can see it.

Comment: @team - use `df1['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date']+ ' ' + df1['time'], dayfirst=True)` - change first row of my answer

Comment: yes finally, amazing, this is really correct answer. Thank you very much. you are a genius, You saved my day. Thank you once again.